# Scanning the serial port periodically to see if the device is connected in QT, QSerialPort

Tags: qt, serial-port

I am trying to scan my serial ports periodically to see if my device is connected or not. Here is what I have done and it works well.  I would like to see if there is a better and optimized way to do so.

1. I created the following timer in my constructor to check the serial port frequently. I made a method (`scanSerialPorts()`) and call it every 1 second.

   ```
   QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
   connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(scanSerialPorts()));

   timer->start(1000);
   ```
2. This is my `scanSerialPorts()` implementation:

   ```
   foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
       currentPortName = info.systemLocation();
   }

   if (currentPortName == "My Desired PortName" ) {
       updateSettings();

       if ( !serial->isOpen()){
           qDebug() << "Serial Not Open";
           openSerialPort();
       } 
   } else
   {
       serial->close();
   }
   ```
3. `updateSettings();  // Fills up the serial port parameters.`
4. `openSerialPort();  //Opens up the serial port.`

I used QT examples to write this. Please let me know what you think and how I can make it better.

Answer (score 1):

1. As it is, you only scan the last port, since the rest of the code is outside the `foreach`loop;
2. You close the other (probably not opened) ports instead of the one you're opening
3. Most probably, `availablePorts` won't change during execution, so you could move it outside of the scan function to save some processing time in the timer. The same for `updateSettings()`.